# How do I fix this lookup value formula error?

Tags: powerbi, lookup

I received this error:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

I'm trying to pull in multiple contract status' (Next 7, Next 15, Next 30, Next 90, Next 120, Next 180, > 180 and Expired) and return them to the site master table you see below.

These status are flowing over as a formula, from the contract end date, on Sales Force Contract Status

Here is the formula:

```
Z - Status Flag = LOOKUPVALUE('Sales Force_Contract'[Z - Contract Status],'Sales Force_Contract'[Z Sage ID],viw_SiteMaster[JobNo])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying this formula:

```
Z - Status Flag = calculate(FIRSTNONBLANK('Sales Force_Contract'[Z - Contract Status], 1), 
                  filter(all('Sales Force_Contract'),
                 'Sales Force_Contract'[Z Sage ID] = viw_SiteMaster[JobNo]))
```

and it worked! It had to do with blanks.

I feel like alot of my errors have to do with blanks.

Thanks team!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).